# how can i make a variable in unity that holds multiple variables ? without making a custom class

Tags: unity-game-engine

how can I make a variable in unity that holds multiple variables? without making a custom class
like I want a variable to hold a string and an image so yea thanks for your time and I know I'm a beginner

Comment: [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) and also see fancy things like e.g. [Serializable Dictionary for Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/finally-a-serializable-dictionary-for-unity-extracted-from-system-collections-generic.335797/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options. You can use [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) only if you have two variables, but if you have more than two variables you can use [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) or object array. Here how you can use dictionary:

```
public Image image = null;

private void CreateDictionary()
{
    Dictionary<string, Image> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
    dictionary.Add("Hello", image);
}
```

Here how you can use object array:

```
private void ObjectArray()
{
    object[] variables = new object[4];

    variables[0] = 49;      // int
    variables[1] = "Hello"; // string
    variables[2] = 9.81f;   // float
    variables[3] = true;    // bool

    for (int i = 0; i < variables.Length; i++)
    {
        if (variables[i] is int)
        {
            Debug.Log(variables[i] + " is an integer.");
        }
        else if (variables[i] is string)
        {
            Debug.Log(variables[i] + " is a string.");
        }
        else if (variables[i] is float)
        {
            Debug.Log(variables[i] + " is a float.");
        }
        else if (variables[i] is bool)
        {
            Debug.Log(variables[i] + " is a boolean.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary if you want:

```
Dictionary<string, Image>
```

For each string you'll have a respective Image. However, if you want something more a custom class is the way to go.